# How can I set the path so the programs are always found?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so far, I have installed UBUNTU.
I have installed ROS.
I have installed various relative Programs like Turtle-bot, etc.
When I try to run the programs, the ROS can't find the files. How can I set the path so the programs are always found? it seems that I am doing this the hardway. What is the easyway?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11832/how-can-i-set-the-path-so-the-programs-are-always-found?/) by [MovieMaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/1184/moviemaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-11-07**:
Your question title could be a bit more expressive, "What do i do now?" basically is the underlying theme of 80% of questions here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest taking a look at the introductory tutorials - particularly [configuring the ROS environment.](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment)  That includes information on setting up paths.

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2011-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4